# Size of data, that can be stored in webpart property

Tags: web-part

I have a webpart with property, that is not `WebBrowsable`, and it is `Shared`. The type is text, and I store serialized XML data in it.

My concern is, if any problem might arise, if that data grows. Is there any limit, of how large data (eg. how many characters or bytes) can be saved in WebPart property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default storage size for WebPart properties is quite limited i.e. 1MB for Shared or Personal. However, you can modify this limit in the web.config file

```
      <SharePoint>
          <WebPartLimits MaxZoneParts="50" PropertySize="1048576" />
      </SharePoint>
```

Exception will be thrown if the property storage limit exceeded, together with property values not being saved.

Hope it helps!